# Entering text in the input text box accidently opens file open dialogue

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, desktop, dialog

I was entering a search text in the input text box of a website. But the first character I typed opened the "file open dialogue" (file explorer). I was using Windows 10 and Chrome. I started typing the character "o".  This was not programmed behavior, my institution owns the site. After some meddling with the mouse and desktop it disappeared. But I don't remember how. I cannot reproduce this error. Does anybody have an idea what caused it?

Comment: Yes, that is the answer. Thanks @gronostaj

Answer (score 1):

You have accidentally pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or it got stuck. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> is a common keyboard shortcut for *Open*.